# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: database-link, oracle-9i

I have created a database link to a remote database, MIGRERDOSSIER.US.ORACLE.COM, then I use it to insert records in a table in a local database. Here is the request I am trying to execute:

```
insert into 
    Dossier(num_dossier,indice,code_service,num_secteur,date_depot,type_dossier,SUP_DECL_ARE,SUP_DECL_CE,SUP_DECL_HE,SUP_DEF_ARE,SUP_DEF_CE,SUP_DEF_HE)
    select s.num_dossier,s.indice,s.code_service,s.num_secteur,s.date_depot,s.cod_sous_typ,s.SUP_DECL_ARE,s.SUP_DECL_CA,s.SUP_DECL_HE,s.SUP_DEF_ARE,s.SUP_DEF_CA,s.SUP_DEF_HA
    from MIGRERDOSSIER.US.ORACLE.COM@Dossier s
```

but Oracle is displaying the error `ORA  00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

I can't figure the problem with my request, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not missing the ; at the end, are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for using the database link is incorrect, you've got the link and table identifiers in the wrong order.

It should be:

```
select ... from table_name@db.link.name
```

Having too many `.` in a table name results in an ORA-00933 error, like you're getting.

Comment: Yes I've already discovered this and that worked @Mat..Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: I think I can avoid that by defining a synonym for  my distant table :) right ?

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't. The fact that the table you're querying isn't local is rather important information, I wouldn't hide it behind a synonym.